# Configuring Angular2 with .NET

Tags: .net, angular

Hi guys i'm trying to configure an angular 2 app with .NET webProject but i encounter some problems which i don't know how to fix or have any idea why they arise.

A snapshot on the errors. all occur in type def files
[image]
I'm using webpack

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './App_UI/entry/main.ts', 
    output: {
        path: './App_UI/bundle',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    }
};
```

package.json looks like this

```
"name": "search-engine",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.19",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "~2.4.1",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^4.4.2",
    "typescript": "^2.1.5",
    "typings": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
```

and tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false
  }
}
```

What am i missing ?

the errors are when building the project build failed:1 | succeeded 1
some errors for example state: `cannot find name "schedulre","number". et.
I guess it does not know about "Promise, Observable, Action".

Comment: When you have an error and you ask a question about that error you need to **include that error as text**, please do not use screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to create a project using angular-cli and just copy what i need from it, include the files within the web project and that is it.